# Convert recorded video into array of UIImages

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, video, video-processing

I'm writing a live-video tracking algorithm with openCV but am trying to test it using a recorded video instead of frames captured in real-time. I have a CADisplayLink that I can synchronize with the video's FPS but can only find information about converting images into a video (the other way around). Can anyone provide a simple example of how to accomplish this? Or provide information of why this is not so simple?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I must have been searching too specifically for my situation and have just found a tutorial describing what I'm looking for from http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html using the cv::VideoCapture object and read() function. Maybe this will be of use to someone.